# Cannot run multiple kernels (Python versions) in jupyterhub

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, python-3.4, jupyter, jupyterhub

Hi I am running a notebook server with jupyterhub but I am unable to access different kernels (version of python).

I have the various enronments setup correctly, and when I type

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

I get the following output

```
Available kernels:              
bash       /home/username/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/bash  
python2    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2                  
python3    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

But when the jupyterhub launches it only finds the Python3 kernel available?

How can I get it to detect all available python versions??

```
cat /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2/kernel.json  

{                                                   
"display_name": "Python 2",
"language": "python",
"argv": [
"/opt/anaconda3/envs/py27/bin/python2.7",
"-m",
"ipykernel",
"-f",
"{connection_file}"                                                        
]       
}

cat /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json  

{ 
"language": "python",                                                 
"display_name": "Python 3",
"argv": [
"/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3",
"-m",
"ipykernel",
"-f",
"{connection_file}"                                                        
] 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the priviledges on `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2/kernel.json` file. If it's not readable for everybody, than you won't see it in Jupyter.

It should have 644 privileges:

```
# ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  158 Apr 15 12:47 kernel.json
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed the ipykernel for python2.7 ?

```
pip2.7 install ipykernel
python2.7 -m ipykernel install --user
```